# MAUI ListView vs. WPF ListView: why does MAUI give a StackOverflow exception when setting ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, listview, saxon, maui

I am trying to use a MAUI `ListView` like I seem to be able to use a WPF `ListView`, namely by simply assigning to `ItemsSource` an object that is an `IEnumerable` and where the items in the `IEnumerable` override `ToString`.

In that case a WPF ListView for me simply shows the items, whether I used .NET built-in types or values from the library, SaxonCS, I want to use; with MAUI for some reasons I don't understand the approach works for me with a simple `string[]` but not with an `XdmItem[]` or `XdmValue`, taken from the `SaxonCS` library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonCS/), in that case I end up with a `StackOverflow` exception without a detailed stack trace, but showing "System.StackOverflowException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll". (Note all tests have been done only on Windows, that is obvious for WPF, but for MAUI as well so far I am only interested in the Windows use).

So WPF is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfXdmViewTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfXdmViewTest1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="XdmView"></ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static Processor processor = new Processor();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //var values = new string[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

        //var values = new XdmItem[] { new XdmAtomicValue("foo"), new XdmAtomicValue(3), new XdmAtomicValue(true) };

        var xqueryCompiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
        xqueryCompiler.BaseUri = new Uri("urn:from-string");
        var xqueryExecutable = xqueryCompiler.Compile("(1 to 5) ! <item>Item {.}</item>");
        var xqueryEvaluator = xqueryExecutable.Load();

        var xdmValue = xqueryEvaluator.Evaluate();

        XdmView.ItemsSource = xdmValue;
    }
}
```

and runs fine and displays what I expect (the `ToString()` result of each `XdmItem` in the `ListView`) while MAUI is similar with

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MAUIXdmViewTest1.MainPage">

    <ListView x:Name="XdmView"></ListView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

and

```
using Saxon.Api;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static Processor processor = new Processor();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //var values = new string[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

        //var values = new XdmItem[] { new XdmAtomicValue("foo"), new XdmAtomicValue(3), new XdmAtomicValue(true) };

        var xqueryCompiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
        xqueryCompiler.BaseUri = new Uri("urn:from-string");
        var xqueryExecutable = xqueryCompiler.Compile("(1 to 5) ! <item>Item {.}</item>");
        var xqueryEvaluator = xqueryExecutable.Load();

        var xdmValue = xqueryEvaluator.Evaluate();

        XdmView.ItemsSource = xdmValue;

    }

}
```

but fails with a StackOverflow exception in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

Minimal but complete repos are https://github.com/martin-honnen/MAUIXdmViewTest1/tree/XdmValueAsItemsSource and https://github.com/martin-honnen/WpfXdmViewTest1/tree/XdmValueAsItemsSource.

The branches that work with only a string[] array with both MAUI and WPF are https://github.com/martin-honnen/WpfXdmViewTest1 and https://github.com/martin-honnen/MAUIXdmViewTest1, respectively.

Unfortunately to use SaxonCS you need at least an [evaluation license](https://www.saxonica.com/download/download.xml), I am not sure I will find someone here taking the effort to request one to run/test on its own.

But any hints are appreciated in what way the MAUI ListView is that different to a WPF ListView that it gives a StackOverflow exception with the same approach of assigning to ItemsSource.

Comment: only guessing, but possibly your data source has a circular reference that WPF ignores but MAUI does not

Comment: While the underlying XDM data model and its representation as C#/.NET classes is somehow complex I don't see any circularity in the assigned ItemsSource, at least neither in the sample constructing a simple array `var values = new XdmItem[] { new XdmAtomicValue("foo"), new XdmAtomicValue(3), new XdmAtomicValue(true) };` nor in the mildly more real use case of returning an `XdmValue` which is a sequence of five `XdmNode` items.

Comment: At Saxonica we have not done any testing with MAUI. Martin Honnen has reported problems with this platform which we have not yet investigated.

Comment: The problems I had so far with SaxonCS and MAUI were specific to the platforms Android (unresolved crash) and iOS/MacCatalyst (license resolution uses unsupported DSA en/decryption); on Windows SaxonCS runs fine in MAUI, as far as I have tested to run XPath, XQuery or XSLT. Only my attempt above to display in a ListView is somehow not working. Still hope someone here can give me clue as to why the ItemsSource assigment gives a StackOverflow.

Comment: As a workaround I tried to change `var xdmValue = xqueryEvaluator.Evaluate();` to `var xdmValue = xqueryEvaluator.Evaluate().Select(i => i.ToString());`, that way I get the expected output  with SaxonCS and MAUI (tested under Windows). Still no idea why the original code gives the StackOverflow exception as I kind of understand/expect the `ToString()` being done under the hood on the `ItemsSource` by the MAUI ListView control.